# Terraform: possible to use an enterprise github repo with sub-directories as module source?

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to use an enterprise Github repo with sub-directories as a Terraform module source? Reading the Module source [doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html), I'm attempting to use the Generic Git repository type, however, it does not appear as though its possible to access sub-directories using this method. E.g.,

```
module "awesome" {
 source = "git::https://github.enterprise.com/org/repo.git//path//to//module"
 # Note: I've also tried without the "forced source type."
}
```

Unfortunately `terraform get` downloads the entire repository contents. 
I can't say that I would expect this to work (given that its not explicitly supported) but perhaps someone out there has figured it out. If not, perhaps it could be a feature request.

Comment: Looks like that's not possible - we created organization 'terraform' and using one module per repo. Enterprise now priced per user instead of a number of repositories.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using a GitLab repo with sub-directories as a Terraform module source: 
module "awesome" { source = "git::ssh://git@gitlab.example.com/org/repo.git//modules/awesome" }

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's enterprise or not. Maybe this was a bug at some point because I've used this method successfully for modules using internal bitbucket repositories in terraform 0.11.x and 0.12.x.